# How to get Usercontrol object 'X' from X's Button(i.e. Button inside the X) onclick event

Tags: c#, user-controls, onclick, handler

Hello guys i am working on a Windows Form application in .Net C#.

Now i have a User control with a button inside it.
however i had to write the on-click handler in the main form rather than inside the user-control itself.
Now i want to know if there is anyway i can get the User-control object in the Button's on-click Handler. Since i had to make use of them few more times in the same form. I want to know which User-control's Button was click.

```
User Control
Button
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the UserControl raising a Custom Event that passes out the source UserControl that the Button was clicked on:

SomeUserControl:

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{

    public event ButtonPressedDelegate ButtonPressed;
    public delegate void ButtonPressedDelegate(SomeUserControl sender);

    public SomeUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonPressed != null)
        {
            ButtonPressed(this); // pass the UserControl out as the parameter
        }
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        someUserControl1.ButtonPressed += new SomeUserControl.ButtonPressedDelegate(SomeUserControl_ButtonPressed);
        someUserControl2.ButtonPressed += new SomeUserControl.ButtonPressedDelegate(SomeUserControl_ButtonPressed);
        someUserControl3.ButtonPressed += new SomeUserControl.ButtonPressedDelegate(SomeUserControl_ButtonPressed);
    }

    void SomeUserControl_ButtonPressed(SomeUserControl sender)
    {
        // do something with "sender":
        sender.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event:

```
public delegate void ButtonClicked();
public ButtonClicked OnButtonClicked;
```

You can then subscribe the event anywhere, for instance, in your MainForm, you have a user control called demo;

```
demo.OnButtonClicked +=() 
{
   // put your actions here.
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. strange it showed me syntax error near (). Its says "Invalid expression term ')'"

Comment: use Visual studio intellisence(type += then type tab key), the code is just a skeleton!

Answer (score 0):

Just walk the .Parent() chain until you find a Control that is the same Type as your UserControl.  In the example below, the UserControl is of Type `SomeUserControl`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        someUserControl1.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        someUserControl2.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        someUserControl3.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Control uc = btn.Parent;
        while (uc != null && !(uc is SomeUserControl))
        {
            uc = uc.Parent;
        }

        uc.BackColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show(uc.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer :) but am waiting for few more answers... after that i will tag it as answer..

Comment: The need to do this is indicative of a really bad design.  It would be better to have the UserControl raise a custom event with the UserControl passed out as a parameter of that event.